# How to restart docker for windows process in powershell?

Tags: powershell, docker, docker-for-windows

I want to restart `docker for windows` (now known as Docker Desktop) in powershell.

I would like to do it with one command in PowerShell.

[image]

May I implement it?

When using `Restart-Service *docker*`:

[image]

Comment: `Restart-Service *docker*` perhaps?

Comment: @Theo pity to be invalid...

Comment: Docker can be stopped and started through powershell, a similar idea is shared in this post https://thecodeframework.com/start-docker-desktop-on-windows-start-up-without-user-logon/

Answer (score 32):

Kill and restart the docker process:

```
$processes = Get-Process "*docker desktop*"
if ($processes.Count -gt 0)
{
    $processes[0].Kill()
    $processes[0].WaitForExit()
}
Start-Process "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Docker Desktop.exe"
```

In the `if` clause I check if any running docker process has been found. There should never be more than 1 instance of "Docker Desktop" running so you can then kill the first one in the list.

To restart you need to know the full path of the "Docker Desktop.exe" file on your computer.

Comment: After the update it is actually `Docker Desktop` instead of `Docker for Windows`

Answer (score 14):

On windows, open Docker desktop and click on the debug icon then restart. You can also consider "reset to factory defaults"

[image]

Comment: OP explicitly asked to do it from Powershell.

Answer (score 10):

You can user in powershell:

```
restart-service *docker*
```

Or int the Docker QuickStart Terminal:

```
docker-machine restart
```

Comment: cannot work... just kill the docker daemon, but docker cannot restart.

Comment: restart-service *docker* does in fact stop and start com.docker.service, which is what we're after.  But it's not successful; after you do it, you have a broken docker (can't connect, can't do anything)

Comment: While this does restart the docker desktop service (com.docker.service), it doesn't result in a working docker. I'm pretty sure you have to recreate the Hyper-V instance to do that?

Comment: "& $Env:ProgramFiles\Docker\Docker\DockerCli.exe -SwitchDaemon" resolves the problem, but you might need to run it twice.

Answer (score 4):

Similar to Sebastian L's comment above, but slightly cleaner & faster if you know whether you are currently running Linux or Windows containers.

If running Linux Containers

```
    Stop-Service *docker*        
    Start-Service *docker*
    &$Env:ProgramFiles\Docker\Docker\DockerCli.exe -SwitchLinuxEngine
```

If running Windows Containers

```
    Stop-Service *docker*        
    Start-Service *docker*
    &$Env:ProgramFiles\Docker\Docker\DockerCli.exe -SwitchWindowsEngine
```

-SwitchDaemon toggles from one to the other (Linux to Windows or Windows to Linux) which is why you have to do it twice.