# Github Action failing to Build Images for the plugins being used in workflow

Tags: kubernetes, github-actions, alpine-linux

I am trying to use a plugin in my eks based k8s cluster,
I am using a Github Action controller that spawns on demand Container as Self Hosted runner
When the Github action start this plugin or any other that needs to build itself as a docker image  fails with below error, any thoughts or ideas ?
This is my self hosted runner image Link

FYI : If i run a standalone alpine container in the cluster all typical cmd works, and this also works with default ubuntu based self hosted runner, so i dont think its the cluster

```
/usr/local/bin/docker build -t 60e226:1b6fc15462134e6fb8520b7df48cf7fd -f  "/runner/_work/_actions/aquasecurity/trivy-action/master/Dockerfile"      "/runner/_work/_actions/aquasecurity/trivy-action/master"
Sending build context to Docker daemon  644.6kB

Step 1/5 : FROM ghcr.io/aquasecurity/trivy:0.[3](https://github.com//docker-images/actions/runs/4134005760/jobs/7147011143#step:3:3)7.1
0.37.1: Pulling from aquasecurity/trivy
c158987b0551: Pulling fs layer
67a7d067ef7d: Pulling fs layer[6]Download complete
67a7d067ef7d: Pull complete
2ec1cdd48f38: Verifying Checksum
2ec1cdd48f38: Download complete
2ec1cdd48f38: Pull complete
fe56e6aa700e: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:7c[16](https://github.com//docker-images/actions/runs/4134005760/jobs/7147011143#step:3:16)7f7f3002948f1ec099555aa968bd8b8b097780603a38cc801fe965da0a69
Status: Downloaded newer image for ghcr.io/aquasecurity/trivy:0.37.1
 ---> c3e68408cd24
Step 2/5 : COPY entrypoint.sh /
 ---> 1f1da443ea86
Step 3/5 : RUN apk --no-cache add bash curl npm
 ---> Running in 647f7f479cac
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.[17](https://github.com//docker-images/actions/runs/4134005760/jobs/7147011143#step:3:17)/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
48ABC73BEB7F0000:error:0A000086:SSL routines:tls_post_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:[18](https://github.com//docker-images/actions/runs/4134005760/jobs/7147011143#step:3:18)89:
WARNING: Ignoring https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.17/main: Permission denied
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.17/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
48ABC73BEB7F0000:error:0A000086:SSL routines:tls_post_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:1889:
WARNING: Ignoring https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.17/community: Permission denied
ERROR: unable to select packages:
  bash (no such package):
    required by: world[bash]
  curl (no such package):
    required by: world[curl]
  npm (no such package):
    required by: world[npm]
The command '/bin/sh -c apk --no-cache add bash curl npm' returned a non-zero code: 3
Warning: Docker build failed with exit code 3, back off 6.807 seconds before retry.
```

It was expected to build the docker image and proceed with the github action  workflow

Tried different flavors of image and nothing worked except for **ubunut-latest**

the plugin in question

```
    - name: Run Trivy vulnerability scanner
      uses: aquasecurity/trivy-action@master
      with:
        image-ref: 'test:latest'
        format: 'table'
        exit-code: '1'
        ignore-unfixed: true
        vuln-type: 'os,library'
        severity: 'CRITICAL,HIGH'
```

Comment: Please include your Dockerfile in your question. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker: How to use bash with an Alpine based docker image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40944479/docker-how-to-use-bash-with-an-alpine-based-docker-image)

Comment: this is actually the plugin itself, we dont deploy or build it 
its like u add this to ur github action workflow and that trigggers a docker build,

Comment: one more thing i am not trying to target this specific brand , its for any plugin that u add to workflow, faces same issue

Comment: Right. It's using `ghcr.io/aquasecurity/trivy:0.37.1` which uses an older alpine version. I tried to reproduce the scenario with it and it failed with the same error i.e. `ERROR [2/2] RUN apk add --nocache bash curl npm`. Then, I added `apk update && apk add bash curl npm` and it built. From your perspective, it's a transitive dependency. You need to create an issue on the respective repo to get this fixed. Alternatively, you can build it on your own and plug that instead.

Comment: Here's the Dockerfile that worked: `FROM ghcr.io/aquasecurity/trivy:0.37.1`, `RUN apk update && apk add bash curl npm`, and `CMD ["bash"]`.

Comment: Here's their Dockerfile that fails: https://github.com/aquasecurity/trivy-action/blob/master/Dockerfile.

Comment: Just tested it with GHA and `ubuntu-latest`. It worked fine. See https://github.com/iamazeem/test/actions/runs/4136896033/jobs/7151369290. Seems like it's something to do with your self-hosted runner itself.

Comment: it always works fine with the ubuntu-latest on github, but when we introduce our images as self hosted one, it fails, although they are like ubuntu 22.
I also tried with the 3rd party image that has latest ubuntu https://hub.docker.com/r/summerwind/actions-runner/tags

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251767/discussion-between-ali-and-azeem).

Comment: Right. Observe those "permission denied" warnings for CDN and "packages not found errors". Looks like your self-hosted runner needs to update its repositories. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53710206/docker-cant-build-because-of-alpine-error and https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/issues/386.