# How can I resize the Docker Desktop Virtual Machine on Windows 10 from a PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell, docker, kind

I am attempting to write a PowerShell script (using PS core 7.0) to install and configure a Kubernetes cluster running on Kind on Windows 10 machines used by my teams.  I have a working script to start up and configure the cluster the only issue is that I would like to (need to) ensure the Docker Desktop VM has enough memory available to run a few of our micro services inside the cluster at the same time.

I've got a bit of code cobbled together to perform the task and it works up to the very last step where I attempt to get the docker daemon working again after the restart. As soon as I run the command to do that, the VM is reconfigured back to its previous memory size.

Here's what I have to perform the resizing:

```
        Stop-Service *docker*

    Get-VM DockerDesktopVM | Stop-VM 
    Get-VM DockerDesktopVM | Set-VMMemory -StartupBytes 12888MB
    Get-VM DockerDesktopVM | Start-VM

    Start-Service *docker*

    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51760214/how-to-restart-docker-for-windows-process-in-powershell
    &$Env:ProgramFiles\Docker\Docker\DockerCli.exe -SwitchDaemon
    &$Env:ProgramFiles\Docker\Docker\DockerCli.exe -SwitchDaemon
```

Note: I found the post @ [How to restart docker for windows process in powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51760214/how-to-restart-docker-for-windows-process-in-powershell) which is were I got the last 2 lines.

In researching the issue further I have found that I can use the following single line instead, but I still have the same issue in that the memory size is reverted back once the command is run.

```
&$Env:ProgramFiles\Docker\Docker\DockerCli.exe -SwitchLinuxEngine
```

If I do not run either DockerCli.exe -SwitchDaemon twice or DockerCli.exe -SwitchLinuxEngine once then I get the error:

*error during connect: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.40/containers/json: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon configuration on Window
s, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.*

Is there a better way to go about resizing the VM memory or to shutdown and restart docker without causing the change to be reverted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else who is attempting the same thing, or something similar I got a hint from the Docker Desktop for Windows Community on GitHub that helped me find a solution.  In a nutshell the recommendation was to simply change the settings file directly.  What I found worked was to:

1. Stop the Docker Services (There are 2 of them)
2. Update the settings file (@ ~\AppData\Roaming\Docker\settings.json)
3. Start the Docker Services
4. Switch the Daemon Context to Linux (Same as it was before, but it appears to need a nudge to pick things up after restarting the services).

Here's the PowerShell:

```
 Stop-Service *docker*
 $settingsFile = "$env:APPDATA\Docker\settings.json"
 $settings = Get-Content $settingsFile | ConvertFrom-Json
 $settings.memoryMiB = 8192
 $settings | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content $settingsFile
 Start-Service *docker*        
 &$Env:ProgramFiles\Docker\Docker\DockerCli.exe -SwitchLinuxEngine
```