# Reset localhost:80 port

Tags: docker, docker-run

[running containers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwW6S.png)[all containers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgmK1.png)
I've recently started learning docker and after following the tutorial, I ran the following command

`docker run -d -p 80:80 docker/getting-started`

and open up port localhost:80 and saw the docker getting started page. However, I had to run my client's project, whose port was mapped to localhost:80 as well. On account of this, I'm unable to run my client's project on localhost:80. In addition to that, any instance I randomly open up docker and then switch to localhost:80, it redirects to docker's getting started tutorial. I want to reset this localhost:80 port so that when I run my client's project, I can map them to localhost:80. Any method to rectify the issue?

Answer (score 1):

First find you container's ID using:

```
docker ps
```

Supposing it is `e11d9f8bb730`, you can now stop and remove the container with:

```
docker stop e11d9f8bb730
docker rm e11d9f8bb730
```

Run again your container, this time using a different port:

```
docker run -d -p 81:80 docker/getting-started
```

Now your container is running on port 81 and you will be able to run your client's App on port 80.

Comment: The problem is that there aren't any containers running. I've attached screenshots

Comment: What do you see when you go to localhost:80 in the browser?

Comment: Docker's getting started page,i.e. localhost/tutorial

Comment: Then you container is actually running. Go to a terminal and run ``docker ps`` as suggested.

Comment: I checked it again. Same results, Here's the link: https://imgur.com/a/boX7YOQ

Comment: localhost:80 always maps to localhost/tutorial; in incognito, it returns unable to connect. What's the issue?

Comment: Check this post to see if you are able to see/remove the container. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16840409/how-to-list-containers-in-docker

Comment: Also try this ``sudo systemctl restart docker`` or if you are in Windows restart the service using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51760214/how-to-restart-docker-for-windows-process-in-powershell

Answer (score 1):

First search for the container to see if its open:

```
docker container ls
```

If it's not then the page is probably cached by the browser.
I found this to be especially true when using Chrome.

So, if you don't see your container then use your browsers clear cache tool.

In Chrome this is as easy as right clicking on the page and selecting `inspect`, then right clicking the refresh page icon and selecting `hard refresh`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is stop the container you just started (docker / getting-started). You can open a command prompt, then type this command:

`docker container ls`

You can see which containers are currently running. For example:

[docker containers list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7cp7.png)

You just need to do this command for the stop container:

`docker container stop *yourContainerName*`

Comment: The problem is that there aren't any containers running.  I've attached screenshots

Answer (score 0):

You can use docker to map the container port to any port you choose on your local machine. As an example, you could use your docker getting started and map the port to 8080 instead of 80 like this:

```
docker run -d -p 127.0.0.1:8080:80/tcp docker/getting-started
```

Comment: Tried it... localhost:80 maps to http://localhost/tutorial/ which is still docker's getting started;localhost:8080 is also mapped to docker's getting started

Comment: Are you maybe running two instances of the container? What do you get when you type in `docker ps` - I just tried this exact command above and it worked for me.